# Distance between top edge of paper and header

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr, geometry

*EDIT* : Please apologize me. I forget to add two lines to MWE I think very essential to handle the problems. Please re-check the MWE.

There is parameter defining distance between bottom edge of top margin and first baseline of body, called `\topskip`. Existence of such parameter encourage me to search for parameter defining distance between top edge of paper to (first line of) header text. The aim is to set such a distance to 1.5cm.

At first, I think `\voffset` could be used, from [fancyhdr documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). After some experiment, including elimination of extra 1 inch to 2.1 cm, I find that it will create kind of inconsistency on top margin with option-setting in `geometry` package loading. Before setting `\voffset`, the top margin (distance from top edge of paper to body) is 3 cm. After setting, the margin shrink 0.6 cm roughly.

Moving `\voffset` setting before `\geometry` loading has no effect. Setting `\headheight` to eliminate too-small-warning, adding `\includeheadfoot` option as suggested by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127916/problem-with-geometry-and-headers) make top-margin larger than 3 cm.

The requirement is, **to make the distance between top edge of paper to top edge of header text 1.5 cm, meanwhile preserving top margin of paper 3cm**.

*Note that top margin here is distance between top edge of paper to top edge of paragraph/text body/main*

Here is MWE before setting `\headheight` and `\includeheadfoot`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, onecolumn, oneside, final]{report}

\newlength{\theDistance}
\setlength{\theDistance}{1.5cm}
\addtolength{\theDistance}{-2.1cm} %instead 1 inch extra in fancyhdr documentation
\setlength{\voffset}{\theDistance}
%\usepackage[paper=a4paper,headheight=0pt,left=4cm,top=3cm,right=3cm,bottom=3cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,headheight=27.1pt,left=4cm,top=3cm,right=3cm,bottom=3cm, includeheadfoot, showframe]{geometry}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\topskip}{8.2pt}    

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}
{% 
    \fancyhf{}% 
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}% 
    \fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize {\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont{\bo{Dummy University}}}} 
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}%

\begin{document}
Some text blah blah blah
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `headsep=1.05cm`, `headheight=0.75cm`, `top=1.2cm`. The sum of them is `3cm` and the layout is the one you want.

MWE (I've added two lines, one at `1.5cm` and one at `3cm` just to show that it works, remove them):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, onecolumn, oneside, final]{report}

\usepackage[paper=a4paper,headsep=1.05cm,headheight=0.75cm,left=4cm,top=1.2cm,right=3cm,bottom=3cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\topskip}{8.2pt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\section{test}
Some text blah blah blah

% this is just to show the correct layout

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw ($(current page.north west) +(0,-1.5cm)$) --
          ($(current page.north east) +(0,-1.5cm)$);
    \draw ($(current page.north west) +(0,-3cm)$) --
          ($(current page.north east) +(0,-3cm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Have followed option - order in geometry, result:

distance between top edge of paper to top edge of header text: 0.89 cm

top margin of paper (distance between top edge of paper to top edge of paragraph/text in body/main part of page: 2.39cm

Comment: @aggy Did you remove the line `\setlength{\voffset}{\theDistance}` from your document?

Comment: Now it is removed, but bottom margin still isn't OK. Bottom edge of paper to last baseline is about 4 cm. To a footer text is 3.5 cm.

Comment: By decreasing `bottom` option to 2 cm, it solves. It will be nice to know the logic behind this decrement.